# Android - Asynctask not passing data into private array?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Trying to use asynctask for lazy loading. Its 75% working fine; able to run method in `doInBackground()`. But UI is not updated after loading. I realised that the contents are not stored in the arrays that I declared which they are supposed to(if I didn't use asynctask). Saw `onProgressUpdate` and `publishUpdate` but not sure how to use them. After running `searchContent()`, data are being stored in `mStrings[]` and `dStrings[]` so that it can be passed to my adapter. Any help?

HelloClass.java

```
public class HelloClass extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

ProgressDialog dialog;
private String[] mStrings = {};
private String[] dStrings = {};

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    new TheTask().execute();        

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);         
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, dStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

protected class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HelloClass.this, "Retrieving Information", "Please wait for few seconds...", true, false);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        searchContent();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void searchContent()
{
    String imageC = "";
    String textC = "";


    try {

        URL url = new URL(targetURL);

        // Make the connection
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            if(line.contains("../../"))
            {

                String xyz = line.substring(0,xyz.indexOf('"'));
                imageC = xyz +";";                  
                mStrings = imageC.split(";");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            if(line.contains("../../") == false)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            if (line.contains("Nametag"))
            {
                int startIndex = line.indexOf("Gnametag") + 10;
                int endIndex = line.indexOf("<", startIndex + 1);
                String gname = line.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
                textC = textC.replaceAll("</span>", "");
                textC += "Name: "+gname+ "\n";
            }                   

                if (line.contains("Age"))
                {
                    textC += "Age: "+reader.readLine() + "\n" + ";";
                    textC = textC.replaceAll("                  ", "");
                dStrings = textC.split(";");
                }

            if (line.contains("Last Update"))
            {
                reader.close();
            }                               
        }           

        // Close the reader
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }


}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] text;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] t) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    text = t;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
```

EDITTED:

```
protected class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HelloClass.this, "Retrieving Information", "Please wait for few seconds...", true, false);
    }

    protected void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        searchContent();
        MyResultClass result = new MyResultClass();
        result.mStrings = mStrings;
        result.dStrings = dStrings;
        return result;
    }   
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

class MyResultClass
{ 
    public String[] mStrings; 
    public String[] dStrings; 

}
```

Comment: You would override onProgressUpdate in your AsyncTask, which is run in the UI Thread. In doInBackground you would call progressUpdate to feed data to that callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use Classvars in doInBackground. Build up a result object and pass it to onPostExecute, which is run in UI-Thread. There you can set your String[]s or adapter or whatever you want.

AND what gwa sais. I just saw, that my "solution" is just a "better practice", I guess ... of course you have to make the adapter aware of the change. That is either you tell it, that its underlying datastructure has changed or you change the datastructure by using the adapter's methods.

```
protected class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyResultClass >{

protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HelloClass.this, "Retrieving Information", "Please wait for few seconds...", true, false);
}

protected MyResultClass doInBackground(String[]... params) {
    searchContent();
    MyResultClass result = new MyResultClass();
    result.mStrings = mStrings;
    result.dStrings = dStrings;
    return result;
}   
protected void onPostExecute(MyResultClass result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
// Set new adapter-values here.  
}
}

class MyResultClass
{ 
    public String[] mStrings; 
    public String[] dStrings; 
}
```

I hope you know [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Website about AsyncTask?

Comment: I have got 2 values to be passed. Is it possible to pass to postexecute?

Comment: Sure, just make yourself an inner "ResultClass". It can be as dumb as 
class ResultClass{ public String val1; public String val2; } or even more easy: String[] if it is both Strings you are passing.

Comment: Sorry, so I put the inner class in my doInBackground? And in postExecute i add return val1 and val2?

Comment: No. In your class, outside the AsyncTask, you declare a class. For Example "class MyResultClass{ String[] mStrings; String[] dStrings; }" Then, in your AsyncTask Implementation, you use that class as a returnType for doInBackground. So in doInBackground you would write something like "MyResultClass result = new MyResultClass(); result.mStrings = Blah; result.dStrings = Blubb; return result;" Now again you make that Type your ParameterType in onPostExecute. So the signature is "protected void onPostExecute(MyResultType result)". And there you can use your results on the UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Apologies, I'm not sure what do I put for the "Blah" and "Blubb" and am having error for return result; I tried to to remove as much errors but its not working still. I have included my current editted codes in the above question

Comment: I edited my answer by adding your code with some changes. I guess this should help you kill some of those Exceptions. You should consider returning "MyResultClass" from searchContent if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter keeps its own data structure internally. That means that if you want to change its status you have to operate directly on it.

In your case you should set again mStrings and dStrings in your adapter when the work is done.

publishUpdate and onProgressUpdate are meant to be used when you want to interact with the UI while the task is running, for example when you want to show a progress bar.

Comment: I have a progress dialog displayed when my doinbackground is running. Where should I declare my mStrings and dStrings?

Comment: What kind of adapter are you extending? in general onPostExecute you add the results to your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged. I would like to see some more code...

Comment: I am extending baseadapter in my Adapter.java class. Alright I'll update the codes.